# Why does my friend have fewer Pokémon than me?

Tags: pokemon-go

Why does my friend only have 138 spaces in his Pokédex, when I have 142 spaces in the Pokédex?

[image: My Pokédex]

We both play the game on Android and I am pretty sure we both have the same version of the game.

Could it maybe be because my friend got it from Germany while I downloaded the apk? Did I maybe find or hatch special Pokémon that don't appear in the Pokédex before I get them? Is there even more Pokémon? Do I have special powers?

Comment: I have proposed an edit that cleans up the question a bit, as well as removed the comment "do not close this as a duplicate". The comment will not prevent a question from being closed as a duplicate; instead, if someone thinks the question is a duplicate of something that has already been asked, either agree with them by closing the question, or *edit the question, linking the related question, and telling the reader why that question does not answer your specific question, highlighting the differences between both questions.*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As with every main series Pokémon game, the Pokédex will always only display spots up to Pokémon you've seen. In your case, since you've caught an Aerodacyl, you can only see up to number 142, even though there are more Pokémon after it. In your friend's case, he has caught an Omanyte, but no Pokémon after it, so the Pokédex will only go that far.

Comment: Wow, you're pretty quick. Sorry I wasn't really into Pokémon before Pokémon Go (Please don't hit me!).

Answer (score 4):

**The pokedex always displays all the pokemon up to the one with the highest index**

You just have already caught a pokemon with a higher index (142, just the number of aerodactyl in the dex, nothing more, nothing less) in your pokedex than your friend (138).

If your friend caught an aerodactyl his pokedex will be updated and will also show all the indexes until 142.

Say you catch a snorlax, the last entry displayed in your pokedex will be number 143.